# How to store an array of two objects

Tags: ios, xml, nsdictionary

I have two NSDictionary objects that are sub elements to a main element in some xml data I have being returned from my server.

The xml looks like this:

```
<Car>
  <first element1="1" element2="2">
    <second/>
  </first>
  <first element1="1" element2="2">
    <second/>
  </first>
  <first element1="1" element2="2">
    <second/>
  </first>
</Car>
```

I am saving first and second which contain keyvalues into their own NSDictionary object.

The thing is I can have several car elements, so I need to save an array of car elements that contain first and second NSDictionaries, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full XML schematic:

```
<Eng>
    <Result         >
        <Series         >
            <Link/>
            <FMF/>
                <AlsoLink/>
                <Plugins/>
            </FMF>
            <Sheet          >
                <Car>
                    <first            >
                    <second/>
                    </first>
                    <second            >
                    <first/>
                    </second>
                </Car>
            </Sheet>
        </Series>
    </Result>
</Eng>
```

Update to question:

```
this is what my NSXMLParser methods are currently looking like
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
    {
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process
        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"first"]) {
            parsedFirstMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"second"]) {
            parsedSecondMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
        }
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
            self.parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
        }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"first"]) {
            [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries addObject:parsedFirstMutableDictionary];
            [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries addObject:parsedSecondMutableDictionary];
        }
    }

    //etc
```

everything works fine however if there are several first and second nodes when I add pointbreaks to all of them everything is accessed in the correct order, it then goes to the didEndElement method jumps into the first node adds the NSDictionaries to the arrays correctly then it jumps back up to start the parsing and from that point the old values in the parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries that were just added are lost..

any help with this would be hugley appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the first and second in the entity Car?

Comment: I have edited my xml to provide more detail.. also I was wrong i looked at the xml again and second is in actual fact a member of first.. and in turn first a member of car.. I hope this helps

Comment: You can make a model object for Car and then store it in an array, instead of dealing with dictionaries.

Comment: Is there any chance for a code example.. the hierachy is killing my brain. I am trying to get these values into a object inside NSXMLParser so that layer of code is confusing me abit..

Comment: If you can provide what the actual nodes are, I might be able to suggest a way. Do you have control over deciding the xml schema. I feel there is a possibility of improvement.

Comment: http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser is a good tutorial. Note how they're using `setValue: forKey:` to set the properties values to minimize hardcode.

Comment: Just curious: How can he offer a bounty worth 250 when (1) he doesn't have the 75 reputation needed to offer a bounty and (2) he doesn't have 250 reputation points to give away?

Comment: BUG...? lol well I was 286 then dropped below.. so I guess if I tried to offer a bounty now I would be out of luck. any help would be nice.. lol I am completely stuped on this one..

Comment: well turns out I fixed it.. cannot belive I missed it but I had some old code I forgot about that I entered last week that was declaring another Mutable array.. so all sorted now.

Comment: @HurkNburkS If you have fixed the issue. Give your fix as an answer. If you can share more info about the real values in car element, your solution can be optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay just to clear things up, everything with my code is fine its just that I was initalizing parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries twice so their were two objects of it.. when I was playing around with getting the code to work I slipped a peice of code in that I then forgot about... and later rediscovered.

Useless I know... but fixed, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would require a re-write of your implementation, but could you not define 3  NSMutableArray's to store your data in there?

```
 NSMutableArray * _fullCarList;
 NSMutableArray * _parsedFirstMutableDictionary;
 NSMutableArray * _parsedFirstMutableDictionary
```

;

And then add your XML data from their respective mutable dictionaries to corresponding MutableArray, then add the both dictionaries to the fullCarList array?

```
_fullCarList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: _parsedFirstMutableDictionary, _parsedFirstMutableDictionary, nil];
```

**An Array-of-Arrays.**

Then you can just iterate through the _fullCarlist each row in the _fullCarList would have a corresponding first and second mutable dictionary item.

This way all your data is in one giant array and is much more easily accessible. I personally feel that an Array is easier to parse than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but if you want to save *only* the first first and second elements you encounter then try:

```
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    self.carArray = [NSMutableArray array];     // array of car dictionaries
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"first"]) {
        if ([carDictionary objectForKey: @"first"] == nil)
            [carDictionary setObject: attributeDict forKey: @"first"];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"second"]) {
        if ([carDictionary objectForKey: @"second"] == nil)
            [carDictionary setObject: attributeDict forKey: @"second"];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        carDictionary = [NSMutableArray dictionary];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        [self.carArray addObject: carDictionary];
    }
}
```

This will give you an array of cars (dictionaries) with a set of attributes for "first" and "second".

If however you want to keep *all* first and second elements then you can create an array of car dictionaries where "first" and "second" are pointers to arrays of attribute dictionaries.

```
- (void)startTheParsingProcess:(NSData *)parserData
{
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:parserData]; //parserData passed to NSXMLParser delegate which starts the parsing process
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse]; // starts the event-driven parsing operation.
    self.carArray = [NSMutableArray array];     // array of car dictionaries
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"first"]) {
        [firstArray addObject: attributeDict];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"second"]) {
        [secondArray addObject: attributeDict];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        firstArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        secondArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        carDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [carDictionary setObject: firstArray forKey: @"first"];
        [carDictionary setObject: secondArray forKey: @"second"];
   }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Car"]) {
        [self.carArray addObject: carDictionary];
    }
}
```

Oh and lastly you probably want to add these things when the elementName is "Car" in didEndElement.